# option :prompt=>true from f.select not working on edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

I'm having a bit of a trouble on my edit form. For some reason my select helper is not working properly on the edit action. It seems to ignore for some reason the option :prompt=>true and does not show the "Please select" message. But only on the edit action, the new action is working just fine.

the snippet from the form partial:

```
f.select :category_id, @categories, {:prompt => true}
```

the edit action

```
  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.where(:cat_type=>"page").map { |c| [t("category.#{c.slug}",:default=>"#{c.name}"), c.id] }
  end
```

the new action

```
  def new
    @page = Page.new
    @categories = Category.where(:cat_type=>"page").map { |c| [t("category.#{c.slug}",:default=>"#{c.name}"), c.id] }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
f.select :category_id, @categories, :include_blank => "whatever your prompt says"
```

This work for me.

However, I usually try to avoid doing prompts with the rails form helpers because they never seem to behave right.

Alternatively, I've done it this way:

```
f.select :category_id, @categories.unshift(["whatever your prompt says", value])
```

which pushs the array to the front of your @categories array

Comment: nice one, it would have taken me a long time to figure out the first solution!

Comment: I got this error undefined local variable or method `value' for

Answer (score 4):

From Apidock:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So this would work:

```
f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name), {prompt: 'Please select ...' }, { class: 'form-control' }
```

Answer (score 2):

It works as expected. It does not show the prompt if a value was selected and saved previously.

Prompt vs. Select -- "The main difference is that if the select already has a value, then :prompt will not show whereas the :include_blank always will."

Refer to [this API note](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#271-Prompt-vs-Select).

Answer (score 1):

select option for form for method with prompt value and html options class:

```
f.select(:subcription_with, options_for_select(['paypal', 'stripe']), {:prompt => 'Select Payment Method'}, {:class => "form-control slct-box"})
```

[image]